# Why is `ctrlp` plugin not excluded from loading by including it in `pathogen_disabled`?

Tags: plugin-pathogen

I want to exclude `ctrlp.vim` plugin from loading by setting the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:pathogen_disabled = []
call add(g:pathogen_disabled, 'ctrlp')
call pathogen#infect()
```

Adding other plugins to pathogen_disabled successfully disables them (`vim-airline` for example).

`ctrlp` is still loading. Why?

edit: [here](https://github.com/srustamo/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc) is the full .vimrc

---

Comment: I believe the name of the plug-in is `'ctrlp.vim'` right? If you add that instead, does pathogen disable it properly?

Comment: Tried adding the extension, didn’t work. Other plugins get disabled without the extension.